# \quark_if_nil:NTF seems to find the \q_nil quark in strange places

Tags: expl3, xparse

See below for an example.

The expected behaviour of `\foo` was that of `\fop` but
with `\foo{\textbf{a}, \textbf{b}, \textbf{c}}` I have [THE END] in places where there should not be.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\MappingFunction}{m}
{
  \quark_if_nil:NTF #1
  {[THE~END]~}
  {|#1|\quad}
}

\NewDocumentCommand \Foo
{ > { \SplitList { , } } m }
{ \ProcessList { #1 } { \MappingFunction } }

\NewDocumentCommand \foo { m }
{
  \Foo {#1,\q_nil}
}

%%%%% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\NewDocumentCommand{\MappingFunctionI}{m}
{
  \tl_if_eq:nnTF {#1}{@@@}
  {[THE~END]~}
  {|#1|\quad}
}

\NewDocumentCommand \Fop
{ > { \SplitList { , } } m }
{ \ProcessList { #1 } { \MappingFunctionI } }

\NewDocumentCommand \fop { m }
{
  \Fop {#1,@@@}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\fop{ a, b, c, d }\par
\fop{\textbf{a}, \textbf{b}, \textbf{c}}

\foo{ a, b, c, d }\par
\foo{\textbf{a}, \textbf{b}, \textbf{c}}
\end{document}
```

I would be glad to have an explanation.

Comment: You're not passing in an `N`-type argument to `\quark_if_nil:NTF` in the case of `#1` being `\textbf{a}`, hence, what it sees is `\quark_if_nil:NTF \textbf {a} {[THE~END]~} {|#1|\quad}`, evaluates that `\textbf` is not the quark, inserts the second argument (being `{[THE~END]~}` here) and gobbles the first (being `{a}`). The `{|#1|\quad}` is never touched and hence stays where it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're not passing in an `N`-type argument to `\quark_if_nil:NTF`. Instead what `\quark_if_nil:NTF` sees is:

```
\quark_if_nil:NTF \textbf
  {a}
  {[THE~END]~}
```

and after that a trailing `{|\textbf{a}|\quad}`. `\quark_if_nil:NTF` will determine that `\textbf` is not the quark, hence gobble the `T` branch (removing `{a}`) and use the `F` branch (leaving `[THE~END]~` in the input stream). So `[THE~END]~` is printed, and because there is a trailing `{|\textbf{a}|\quad}` as well that one is printed afterwards.

The correct approach would be to use `\quark_if_nil:nTF` to test whether an arbitrary token list is exactly `\q_nil`. So your code should be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\MappingFunction}{m}
{
  \quark_if_nil:nTF {#1}
  {[THE~END]~}
  {|#1|\quad}
}

\NewDocumentCommand \Foo
{ > { \SplitList { , } } m }
{ \ProcessList { #1 } { \MappingFunction } }

\NewDocumentCommand \foo { m }
{
  \Foo {#1,\q_nil}
}

%%%%% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\NewDocumentCommand{\MappingFunctionI}{m}
{
  \tl_if_eq:nnTF {#1}{@@@}
  {[THE~END]~}
  {|#1|\quad}
}

\NewDocumentCommand \Fop
{ > { \SplitList { , } } m }
{ \ProcessList { #1 } { \MappingFunctionI } }

\NewDocumentCommand \fop { m }
{
  \Fop {#1,@@@}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\fop{ a, b, c, d }\par
\fop{\textbf{a}, \textbf{b}, \textbf{c}}

\foo{ a, b, c, d }\par
\foo{\textbf{a}, \textbf{b}, \textbf{c}}
\end{document}
```

And that will behave like you expected.